# How to Add another document to mail merge for the same record

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, mailmerge

Using a code I found on here posted by user dandarii, I can mailmerge a word.doc. When that mail merge is done I'd like to mailmerge a separate word.doc with the same record. I do not want to have to merge the two word.docs to one word.doc

Was thinking about Creating a separate module but got confused. Was thinking of maybing a wdDoc and a wdDoc1?

````
With wdApp
        .Visible = False

        Set wdDoc = .Documents.Open(filePath & firstDoc)

        'Added Code
        strWorkbookName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Name

        wdDoc.MailMerge.MainDocumentType = wdFormLetters

        wdDoc.MailMerge.OpenDataSource _
            Name:=strWorkbookName, _
            AddToRecentFiles:=False, _
            Revert:=False, _
            Format:=wdOpenFormatAuto, _
            Connection:="Data Source=" & strWorkbookName & ";Mode=Read", _
            SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]"

        With wdDoc.MailMerge
            .Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
            With .DataSource
                .FirstRecord = loopRow - 1
                .LastRecord = loopRow - 1
                .ActiveRecord = loopRow - 1

            End With
            .Execute Pause:=False
        End With

        wdApp.Visible = False

        Set TargetDoc = wdApp.ActiveDocument

        TargetDoc.SaveAs2 Filename:=newFilePath & "\" & newFolderName & "- firstDoc.docx"

        wdDoc.Close SaveChanges:=False```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm following the requirement correctly, I think it would make sense to break this up into two procedures: one to handle the loop (not visible in the code in the question), the other to handle mail merge. Something like the code snippets below.

**"Top-level" procedure that handles the loop and everything Excel** (code extract, based on content in question):

```
With wdApp
    .Visible = False

    Set wdDoc = .Documents.Open(filePath & firstDoc)
    Set wdDoc1 = .Documents.Open(filePath & otherDoc)

    'Added Code
    strWorkbookName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Name

    ExecuteMailMerge wdDoc, strWorkbookName, loopRow, _
                     newFilePath, newFolderName, firstDoc

    ExecuteMailMerge wdDoc1, strWorkbookName, loopRow, _
                     newFilePath, newFolderName, otherDoc
```

**Procedure to handle mail merge**:

```
Sub ExecuteMailMerge(wdDoc As Object, strWorkbookName as String, loopRow as Long, _
                     newFilePath as String, newFolderName as String, docName as String)

    With wdDoc.MailMerge
        .MainDocumentType = wdFormLetters
        .OpenDataSource _
          Name:=strWorkbookName, _
          AddToRecentFiles:=False, _
          Revert:=False, _
          Format:=wdOpenFormatAuto, _
          Connection:="Data Source=" & strWorkbookName & ";Mode=Read", _
          SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]"

        .Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
        With .DataSource
            .FirstRecord = loopRow - 1
            .LastRecord = loopRow - 1
            .ActiveRecord = loopRow - 1
        End With
        .Execute Pause:=False
    End With
    Set TargetDoc = wdApp.ActiveDocument

    TargetDoc.SaveAs2 Filename:=newFilePath & "\" & newFolderName & "- " & docName & ".docx"

    wdDoc.Close SaveChanges:=False
End Sub
```